# Adding ads after a certain number of paragraphs within Genesis themework

Tags: genesis-theme-framework, adsense

I am so close I can feel it. I am trying to get an ad block to show up after say 2 paragraphs. Currently I am using the following code in my functions.php to put the adblock before the last paragraph.

I cannot for the life of me find the correct code to get this done.

```
function ads_added_above_last_p($text) {
if( is_single() ) :
    $ads_text = '<div class="wpselect_middle_content">My Ad Code Here</div>';
    if($pos1 = strrpos($text, '<p>')){
        $text1 = substr($text, 0, $pos1);
        $text2 = substr($text, $pos1);
        $text = $text1 . $ads_text . $text2;
    }
endif;
return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'ads_added_above_last_p');
```

If I play with the second $text string and put $pos2 it works perfectly BUT it duplicates all of the text within the post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found `explode()` to be useful when trying to break strings apart. This code creates an array of paragraph chunks, inserts the new block after two paragraphs and concatenates it back into a string for output.

```php
function insert_ad_block( $text ) {

    if ( is_single() ) :

        $ads_text = '<div class="wpselect_middle_content">My Ad Code Here</div>';
        $split_by = "\n";
        $insert_after = 2; //number of paragraphs

        // make array of paragraphs
        $paragraphs = explode( $split_by, $text);

        // if array elements are less than $insert_after set the insert point at the end
        $len = count( $paragraphs );
        if (  $len < $insert_after ) $insert_after = $len;

        // insert $ads_text into the array at the specified point
        array_splice( $paragraphs, $insert_after, 0, $ads_text );

        // loop through array and build string for output
        foreach( $paragraphs as $paragraph ) {
            $new_text .= $paragraph; 
        }

        return $new_text;

    endif;

    return $text;

}
add_filter('the_content', 'insert_ad_block');
```